# iOS: Is there a way to determine which UIControlEvent the sender came from?

Tags: ios

I'm routing different UIControlEvent to one event handler. Wondering is there a way to determine which UIControlEvent the sender came from? e.g. (Touch Up Inside, Editing Did Begin, etc...)

```
- (IBAction) MultipleEvents: (UITextField *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a second parameter UIEvent* which is going to have a "type".

```
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Comment: Is there a way to attach this using IB? or Do I have to use `addTarget`?

Comment: Not sure how would you hook this up to an Event?

Comment: If you use IBAction instead of void you can attach it from Interface Builder. Sorry for the bad example.

Comment: I attached using IB, but How can I determine event as `UIEvent` to which `UIControlEvent` e.g. `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin` and
`UIControlEventEditingDidEnd`

I think I'm still missing the event information, because `event` logged nil or 0 (if I changed its type to `UIControlEvent`).

Comment: I noticed the same thing you did... it seems that you can know if it was a touch or a keyboard event, but not the exact type :( ; it seems that you should use different selector for each control event